# Swagger + Keycloak + Bearer token

Tags: spring-boot, authentication, swagger, documentation-generation

I am working on a micro service documentation. Our project uses bearer token to auth flow.

All seems fine except that Swagger is adding `Bearer: XXXXXX` token into request headers.

My problem is that i must send in headers `Authorization: bearer XXXXXXX` how can i do that? I am using Swagger with spring boot.

```
package XXXXXXX.config;

import static springfox.documentation.builders.PathSelectors.regex;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

import springfox.documentation.builders.PathSelectors;
import springfox.documentation.builders.RequestHandlerSelectors;
import springfox.documentation.service.*;
import springfox.documentation.spi.DocumentationType;
import springfox.documentation.spi.service.contexts.SecurityContext;
import springfox.documentation.spring.web.plugins.Docket;
import springfox.documentation.swagger2.annotations.EnableSwagger2;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

@Configuration
@EnableSwagger2
public class SwaggerConfig {

    @Value("${keycloak-role.app}")
    private String roleApp;

    @Bean
    public Docket swaggerApi() {
        return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
                .select()
                .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.basePackage("getnet.gs.controller"))
                .build()
                .apiInfo(metaData())
                .securitySchemes(Arrays.asList(apiKey()))
                .securityContexts(Collections.singletonList(securityContext()));
    }
    private ApiKey apiKey() {
        return new ApiKey("Bearer", "Authorization", "header");
    }
    private SecurityContext securityContext() {
        return SecurityContext.builder().securityReferences(defaultAuth()).forPaths(PathSelectors.regex("/.*")).build();
    }

    private List<SecurityReference> defaultAuth() {
        final AuthorizationScope authorizationScope = new AuthorizationScope(this.roleApp, "Credenciais do APP (TERMINAL)");
        final AuthorizationScope[] authorizationScopes = new AuthorizationScope[]{authorizationScope};
        return Collections.singletonList(new SecurityReference("Bearer", authorizationScopes));
    }


    private ApiInfo metaData() {
        ApiInfo apiInfo = new ApiInfo(
                "XXX- MS log",
                "XXXAPI MS log",
                "1.0",
                "Terms of service",
                new Contact("XXX", "https://confluence.XXXX.com.br:8444/#all-updates", "XXXX@getnXXXXet.com.br"),
               "Apache License Version 2.0",
                "https://confluence.XXXX.com.br:8444/#all-updates");
        return apiInfo;
    }
}
```

CURL for the request:

```
curl -X POST --header 'Content-Type: application/json' --header 'Accept: application/json' --header 'Bearer: eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsInR5cCIgOiAiSldUIiwia2lkIiA6ICI0Smd1Y0t6NVZ4RWNnWXFXQW1yTnFCd0dITFJ5ekZxRGJYTHZ4NzRfZzY0In0.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' -d '{ ..... }' 'http://localhost:40070/log'
```

And it only works like this:

```
curl -X POST --header 'Content-Type: application/json' --header 'Accept: application/json' --header 'Authorization: bearer eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsInR5cCIgOiAiSldUIiwia2lkIiA6ICI0Smd1Y0t6NVZ4RWNnWXFXQW1yTnFCd0dITFJ5ekZxRGJYTHZ4NzRfZzY0In0.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' -d '{ ..... }' 'http://localhost:40070/log'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can type in the swagger authorize the text "bearer" before  the token.

Example: `bearer {token}`

[image: image swagger authorize]

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30645414)